# Merging pulled changesets to a feature branch in Mercurial

Tags: version-control, mercurial, branching-and-merging

I created a feature branch from my main (`default`) branch. (i.e. `hg branch feature/name`).

I did a few commits there.
Now I want to push this branch and create a pull-request. But, before doing this, I'd like to make my feature branch up-to-date.

So, I started with `hg pull` command, and it downloaded a couple of changesets.
Then I proceeded with `hg update`, but Mercurial said that nothing was updated (`0 files updated, 0 files merged, 0 files removed, 0 files unresolved`).

So, it looks like new changesets were applied only to `default` branch, but not to my feature branch.

How should I apply those changesets to my feature branch?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You next merge default into your feature branch with:

```
hg merge default
```

That merges the most "recent" head" with the branch label "default" into your currently checked out branch.  You'll need to do a `hg commit` afterward if the merge creates a new changeset (which it will unless there are no new changes in `default` since last you merged it in.